# Google analytics v3 Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError User does not have any Google Analytics account. [403]

Tags: .net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using google analytics v3 api for some automation of reporting of google analytics data.

```
string scope_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";
string client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
string key_file = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-privatekey.p12";
string key_pass = "notasecret";
AuthorizationServerDescription desc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;
//key: Load up and decrypt the key
X509Certificate2 key = new X509Certificate2(key_file, key_pass, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
//client: we're using the AssertionFlowClient, because we're logging in with our certificate
AssertionFlowClient client = new AssertionFlowClient(desc, key) { ServiceAccountId = client_id, Scope = scope_url };
OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient> auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(client, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);
//gas: An instance of the AnalyticsService we can query
// AnalyticsService gas = null;// new AnalyticsService(auth);//not compile
var gas = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
       {
                    Authenticator = auth
       });
//r: Creating our query
DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest r = gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:xxxxxxxx", "2012-09-26", "2012-10-10", "ga:visitors");
//d: Execute and fetch the results of our query
GaData d = r.Fetch();
```

I am getting error `Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError User does not have any Google Analytics account. [403] Errors [   Message[User does not have any Google Analytics account.] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]]`

With the same account when i have use v2.4 version implementation by simple api access it is working.
Don't know why it is working for v2.4 version while not for v3 version of analytics api.

In the google api console i has set Analytics API and google API service service as on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I were able to extract data after adding the email ID [in above code client id] from the google analytic interface.
Detail is given in the link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-analytics-data-export-api/maa_fyjD2cM/2ZxM52BinmUJ

Comment: Infact for one google analytics registeration i have couple of account which are fetching data for two different websites.I have to register that email account to both accounts